# Installing the eslint pre-commit hook errors out

Tags: git, eslint, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I'm trying to install the eslint pre-commit hook (https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-eslint)

This is the entry in my pre-commit file:

```
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-eslint
    rev: 'v7.4.0'
    hooks:
    -   id: eslint
```

However, when I run pre-commit, I get the following:

```
[INFO] Initializing environment for https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-eslint.
[INFO] Initializing environment for https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-eslint:eslint@7.4.0.
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-eslint.
[INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
[INFO] This may take a few minutes...
An unexpected error has occurred: CalledProcessError: Command: ('c:\\users\\username\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\python.exe', '-mnodeenv', '--prebuilt', '--clean-src', '\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\username\\.cache\\pre-commit\\repow421i8dr\\node_env-default')
Return code: 1
Expected return code: 0
Output: (none)
Errors:
     * Install prebuilt node (14.5.0) ..... done.
    symbolic link created for \\?\C:\Users\username\.cache\pre-commit\repow421i8dr\node_env-default\Scripts\nodejs.exe <<===>> node.exe
     * Install npm.js (latest) ... Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
        return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
      File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\nodeenv.py", line 1462, in <module>
        main()
      File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\nodeenv.py", line 1071, in main
        create_environment(env_dir, opt)
      File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\nodeenv.py", line 911, in create_environment
        instfunc(env_dir, src_dir, opt)
      File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\nodeenv.py", line 762, in install_npm_win
        shutil.copy(join(src_dir, npm_ver, 'bin', 'npm.cmd'),
      File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\shutil.py", line 415, in copy
        copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
      File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\shutil.py", line 261, in copyfile
        with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\username\\.cache\\pre-commit\\repow421i8dr\\node_env-default\\src\\npm-latest\\bin\\npm.cmd'


Check the log at C:\Users\username/.cache\pre-commit\pre-commit.log
```

I don't understand what that file is or why eslint needs it.
Eslint works when I use it directly from the terminal, which confirms that it is installed as a standalone and it works as intended too.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to reproduce this crash without pre-commit, just by using nodeenv -- try the following:

```sh
nodeenv nenv --prebuilt --clean-src
```

---

The only way that I can see that this is possible is if you have a nodeenv configuration file which has `with_npm = true` and `npm = ...` (some extremely old version of npm which doesn't ship an `npm.cmd` file)

Could you try removing those contents from your config file? I believe it can be at any of the following places:

- `./tox.ini`
- `./setup.cfg`
- `%HOMEPATH%/.nodeenvrc`

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the error with that comment. It just tells me the environment already exists.

Comment: you may need to `rm -rf nenv`